# How to get the parent tab in a View pager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have an app with four tabs each tab has some Edit Text, some of them need to be populated in order to perform a DB operation, so when the user press the "Save changes" button a method check those Edit text and should focus you to the first that is empty,this work fine but with a problem: the `requestFocus();` will not change the tab if the Edit Text is in other one.

Then I'm trying to use `ViewPager.setCurrentItem(int)` to change the tab before `requestFocus();` but what i cant figure out is:

How to get the Edit text's tab?

Comment: Actually I am not able to understand your problem correctly, are you trying to get the current tab.

Comment: @AmanJain no, the void edit text may or may not be in the current tab so I want to know in witch tab is it

Comment: You can add onFocusChange listener into your tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ViewPager` class doesn't have a method for this.

A quite hacky solution can be that (assumes that you are using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`):

- Call `getParent()` on `EditText` the required number of times for having the parent Fragment. So, if you have a structure like this:
  *Fragment* --> *LinearLayout* --> *EditText* you should call `getParent()` two times. Then cast the `ViewParent` to `Fragment`. You can actually cycle with a `while` loop until you found a `ViewParent` that is an instance of `Fragment`
- Cycle through your adapter fragments

  ```
  for ( int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
      if (adapter.getItem(i) == parentTakenBefore) {
          viewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
          break;
      }
  }
  ```

  and check whether or not the current item is your page

It's more an hack than a real solution, but should works

Hope it helps

**UPDATE**

Added code for cycling through parents

```
boolean isFragment = false;
Fragment fragment = null;
ViewParent currentParent = v.getParent();
while(!isFragment && currentParent != null){
    if (currentParent instanceof Fragment) {
        fragment = (Fragment) currentParent();
        isFragment = true;
    }
    else {
        currentParent = currentParent.getParent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot! [this is what i finally did](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38224106/6470431)

Comment: @WestsideTony updated the answer for a (in my opinion) better solution for finding the Fragment. It works with different nesting levels

Answer (score 0):

Because for some reason neither `View pager` or `adapter` seem to recognize their child I finally came up with a solution.

First create a list of the views which added to the pager

```
static ArrayList<View> tabs= new ArrayList<>();
```

Then when add a new tab also add it to the list

```
tab= inflater.inflate(R.layout.any_tab, container, false);
tabs.add(tab);
```

Finally implement a similar loop like the suggested but this also search for parents

```
//e=The empty text view;

View v=e;
Boolean b=true;
int ctrl=0;
while(b){
    v=(View)v.getParent();//this keep getting the parent view until reaches the tab
    ctrl=0;
    for(View t:tabs){
        if(v==t){
            b=false;
            break;}
        else{ctrl ++;}
    }
}
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(ctrl);//this place you in the right tab
e.requestFocus();//this focus the text view
```